# Empty values and commas returned in the array when if condition not met , JS map arrow function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I have written the following solution to get square of only the positive integers in an array

```js
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2];
const squareList = (arr) => {
  "use strict";
  const squaredIntegers = arr.map((val) => {

    if (val % 2 == 0 && val > 0) {
      return Math.pow(val, 2);
    }

  })

  return squaredIntegers;
};
// test your code
const squaredIntegers = squareList(realNumberArray);
console.log(squaredIntegers);
```

The output I get is 16,,,,1764,36,,

I am expecting just 16,1763,36 and I am trying to understand how commas are shown when the condition is not met .

Any help with the above is appreciated

Comment: add a `.filter(x => x)` at the end of your map statement, it will filter falsy values

Comment: You get `undefined` in those places because the function doesn’t return anything if the condition is false. Just filter them out with `.filter(Boolean)`.

Comment: it helps to just say filter falsey values , any further explanation is appreciated. When I try to explain ' If a val meets the given condition it will be squared and returned then filtered ' Whats the best way to explain the process of filtering? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use filter before map

```js
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2];
const squareList = (arr) => {
  "use strict";
  return arr.filter(value => value>0 && value%2==0).map(value => Math.pow(value, 2));
};
// test your code
const squaredIntegers = squareList(realNumberArray);
console.log(squaredIntegers);
```

Comment: This is wrong. Your array is 4, 42, 6 when the user is asking for the squared values, 16, 1764, and 36.

Answer (score 1):

As Kunal's comment says, `filter` will be useful. It takes a predicate function and returns a copy of the array containing only the values that passed the predicate.

Here's a sample with some other minor code cleanup.

```js
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2];
const squareList = arr => arr
    .filter(a => !(a % 2) && a > 0)
    .map(a => a ** 2);
const squaredIntegers = squareList(realNumberArray);
console.log(squaredIntegers);
```

Comment: Hey shouldn't .filter(a => !(a % 2) && a > 0) be filter(a=>(a%2)&& a>0) ?

Comment: In this case, `!(a % 2)` is equivalent to `a % 2 === 0` which is essentially checking for even numbers. `a%2`, on the other hand, will be checking for odd numbers. You have it correct in your original post.